# elasticsearch returning Incorrect value_count on fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 6 simple documents:

```
{"id":1,"sid":"adf6eb4f-35a0-4099-95d4-00ce3d984cf2","asid":"577ce6b0-b8b7-49af-8528-4e4797027a12","_tid":"21"}
{"id":1,"sid":"adf6eb4f-35a0-4099-95d4-00ce3d984cf2","asid":"577ce6b0-b8b7-49af-8528-4e4797027a12","_tid":"21"}
{"id":2,"sid":"abcdef","asid":"fedcba","_tid":"21"}
{"id":3,"sid":"ghijk","asid":"kjihg","_tid":"21"}
{"id":4,"sid":"lmnop","asid":"ponml","_tid":"21"}
{"id":5,"sid":"prstuv","asid":"vutsrp","_tid":"21"}
```

I am running a value_count aggregation on this dataset using:

```
curl -XGET 'http://poc02.transerainc.com:9200/test/csrs/_search' -d '{"size":0,"aggregations":{"SUMMARY_0_sid":{"value_count":{"field":"sid"}}}}'
```

I am expecting the results to be 6 but I am getting 14!

```
{"took":3,"timed_out":false,"shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":6,"maxscore":0.0,"hits":[]},"aggregations":{"SUMMARY_0_sid":{"value":14}}}
```

this seems to be an obvious error but what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

you should check your elasticsearch [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html) setting for `sid`, is `sid` an `analyzed` field (it most likely is by default)? if it is being treated as an `analyzed` field then "adf6eb4f-35a0-4099-95d4-00ce3d984cf2" would be broken up into 5 different pieces. so total count accumulates to 5+5+1+1+1+1=14